# How do you add all the options from the dropdown to an array in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have three select tags in a dynamic table. You can add as many rows as you want.
The first dropdown has all the products from the products column in the database. The third dropdown gets the prices of all the products selected on the first dropdown of the first column. Although there is many rows for some reason if I select products from the other rows in the first column the prices are added to the first dropdown in the third column and not their respective dropdown but at least it is getting the right prices. How can I add those prices in the dropdown into an array. Eg: $dropdown = $_POST['price'] - All the prices will be in the dropdown variable and I can then use the MultipleIterator() to get the values.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("getSolution.php", success = function (data){
        var options = "";

        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            options += "<option>" + data[i] + "</option>";
        }

        $(".meetingPlace").append(options);
        $(".meetingPlace").change();
    });

    $('#quoteTable1').on('change','.meetingPlace',function () {

        $.getJSON("getSolutionPrice.php?make=" + $(this).val(), success = function (data){
            var options = "";

            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                options += "<option>" + data[i] + "</option>";
            }

            //$(".costing").html("");
            $(".costing").append(options);
        });
    })
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-borderless table-header-bg test" id="quoteTable1">
  <tr><span class="center-block text-center" style="font-weight: bold">Inital Fee</span>
    <th class="text-center" style="width: 5%">D</th>
    <th class="text-center" style="width: 50%">Description</th>
    <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%">Units</th>
    <th class="text-center" style="width: 35%">Cost</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="js-select form-control meetingPlace" name="initial_solution[]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one..">
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="hidden-xs">
      <select class="js-select form-control" id="example-select2" name="initial_quantity[]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one..">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="js-select form-control costing" name="cost[]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one..">
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="form-group text-center">
  <button class="btn btn-primary push-5-r push-10 plusbtn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New Solution</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button class="btn btn-danger push-5-r push-10 minusbtn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Delete Solution</button>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.plusbtn').click(function() {
      $(".test").append('<tr><td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]"></td><td><select class="js-select form-control meetingPlace" name="initial_solution[]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one.."><?php $query = "SELECT * FROM products"; $result = mysql_query($query, $connection); while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ echo "<option>".$row["productName"]."</option>"; }?></select></td><td class="hidden-xs"><select class="js-select form-control" id="example-select2" name="initial_quantity[]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one.."><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option></select></td><td><select class="js-select form-control" name="cost[]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one.."></select></td></tr>');
    });
    $('.minusbtn').click(function() {
      if ($(".test tr").length != 2) {
        $(".test tr:last-child").remove();
      } else {
        alert("You cannot delete first row");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, to get some help in your issue please share us the code that you developed, so we can figure out a solution for your issue.

Comment: *I have a select tag with items in it..* -> OK. Ok *..How do you take those items..* ->There Are Many Ways. *..and add it into an array* ->Which Array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just for a fair idea you can use the following :

```
HTML :
<select name="select_name" size="size in int" multiple="multiple">

PHP : 

$data = $_POST['select_name'];
print_r($data);
```

Comment: <select class="js-select form-control costing" name="cost[]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose one.." size="5" multiple="multiple"></select> this is my select tag

Comment: Please share what you have done till now and the code excerpts so that the same can be debugged.

Comment: try using name="cost" instead of cost[]